# random value is being outputted when I am printing a character

Tags: c

My Code is Below, I am new to coding in C but fluent in Java:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

   int number;
   int firstInitial; 
   int lastInitial; 

   
   printf("\n\nEnter your first initial: ");
   scanf("\n\n%c", &firstInitial);

   printf("\nFirst Initial: %c", firstInitial);
   (int)firstInitial;
   printf("\nFirst Initial Decimal Value: %d", firstInitial);
   
   //Second Initial 
   
   printf("\n\nEnter your Last Initial: ");
   scanf("\n\n%c", &lastInitial);
   printf("\nLast Initial: %c", lastInitial);
   (int)lastInitial;
   printf("\nLast Initial Decimal Value: %d", lastInitial);
   
  
return 0;

}
```

The problem in my output is that after I cast the character into an int, it outputs a random 7 digit number. For example, for first initial I've inputted "a" and received "4194401" instead of 97. The program is supposed to take in a character, and print both the character and it's character decimal value in the ASCII chart.

Comment: `%c` tells `scanf` that the next arg is an `char *` but you gave it an `int *` instead. That's undefined behaviour. It's valid to cast from `int` to `char` but not from `int *` to `char *`. They are not the same.

Comment: The line `(int)lastInitial;` does nothing. The compiler should be giving you a warning that says, "expression result unused".

Comment: @kaylum not the same *portably* or just everywhere ?

Comment: Use arguments like `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion` etc are helpful on GCC, use `-Weverything` on Clang . As a general trend, unpredictable and random results are either due to UB or bad usage of pointers .

Comment: @APJo Don't use `-Weverything` on Clang. It has some obnoxious warnings that aren't really relevant for everyday use. `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` would be a better choice for a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the datatype of `firstInitial` and `lastInitial` to `char`, since you are asking for a character. Also, the `(int)firstInitial` and `(int)lastInitial` statements do nothing - the code works fine with or without them.

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

       int number;
       char firstInitial; 
       char lastInitial; 

   
       printf("\n\nEnter your first initial: ");
       scanf("\n\n%c", &firstInitial);

       printf("\nFirst Initial: %c", firstInitial);
   
       printf("\nFirst Initial Decimal Value: %d", firstInitial);
   
   //Second Initial 
   
       printf("\n\nEnter your Last Initial: ");
       scanf("\n\n%c", &lastInitial);
       printf("\nLast Initial: %c", lastInitial);
   
       printf("\nLast Initial Decimal Value: %d", lastInitial);
   
  
       return 0;

}
```